# When update cordova to 5.4.0 now import or open cordova as new project in eclipse problems

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I have a project generated with cordova Command-Line Interface. I've  always been importing into eclipse JUNO without problems. 
Always got in eclipse to folders, one for NAMEDPROJECT and another called NAMEPROJECT_cordovalib. And configure NAMEPROJECT for reference cordovalib.

But now try to import into new eclipse workspace same cordova project updated to cordova 5.4.0 and show a lot of folders (MainActivity, aapt, debug, 13.1.0, CordovaLib)
Why this amount of folders, I only import from the platforms/Android/ folder in the cordova CML project.

Is eclipse unsuported in cordova. Any other choice for compile to google play. How must I import cordova in eclipse?

Using android API 23, eclipse juno, cordova 5.4.0.

Need help because a have to compile and update the app in google play for a client.

Thanks in advance. Sorry my English.

Comment: The official Android SDK from Google is Android Studio and not Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Joerg I use Apache Cordova for create the projects,  do you now if android studio could import cordova projects?

Comment: Of course Cordova supports Android Studio. Read the docs, under Platform Guides you will find informations about Android Studio.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to read  it right now. I was using eclipse until yesterday and publishing an important project. But now updated my cordova and need to pubish a very simple changes and now i cant import into eclipse. Is more because I'm in a hurry becouse i wanted to do it using eclipse. Now It seem I need change to Android Studio.